# How do I communicate between two dash layouts (on Python)? How do I transfer saved/stored data from one layout to the other (main) layout?

Tags: python, layout, callback, store, plotly-dash

*(My first question and post here)*

Here's my situation:

I have to program a data displaying software on Python dash/plotly. And I am stuck at the part where I have to transfer data from one page of my app.py to the other one (for now offline). Both two Dash layout pages are defined in app.py. The structure is basically the same like the one the third example code in that dash/plotly docu page (https://dash.plotly.com/urls), so I have  *url_bar_and_content_div* defined and assigned to *app.layout*, and I have *layout_page1* and *layout_page2*, as well as *app.validation_layout* in which all these layouts are listed in the *html.Div()... *
(I can't show concrete code because it's for my internship)

I am able to redirect from page 1 to page 2, right now I'm coding the Divs and callbacks of page 2. On page 2, I want to submit and store data of any file I work with, preferably in a *pd.DataFrame* or in a *dict*. And I'm picturing it more or less, that I use an *html.Button()* to "Submit", which after being clicked finally saves the data, "transfers" it to page 1 and redirects the user to page 1 too. And so **here**'s where I am stuck now: How do I transfer that saved/submitted data to *layout_page_1*? How do I even make page 2 store and submit data in a *df* or smth using callbacks to begin with?? I know that using global variables in callbacks is not possible, and I have also ofc looked at the dash docu page for this matter (https://dash.plotly.com/sharing-data-between-callbacks). It hasn't really helped me though, like I didn't know where I should approach my issue with this information, and I also didn't really understand many things. I have never used the *dcc.Store()-component* before, I am not a pro/expert at Python programming, and this is my first internship in which I am working with Dash for the first time...

So how do I approach this problem? Do I have to add *dcc.Store()* to both layout-Divs? Do they have to have the same *id*, must they have to be named *"memory"*,*"local"* or *"session"*, or is it irrelevant? How would I "connect" those two Store-components then, how can I make these two layouts "communicate" with each other and enable smooth data transition from page 2 to page 1 and vice versa??

I'd be so much thankful if someone here would help me out on this, I hope I'll get a response soon, because I have to finish that task in a few weeks. Thanks in advance and cheers!

Edit: @PeterWood Alright, so again, I'll explain what I have to do and I'll use some code to illustrate my problem better!

I have my main *app* program which I always execute, and it contains the following layouts:

```py
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

url_bar_and_content_div = html.Div([
    dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=False),
    html.Div(id='page-content')
])                # just like in https://dash.plotly.com/urls

layout_page1 = html.Div([ ...

      ,html.Div(id="data-display",
                children=[],...),      
    """this is basically the place where the data from page 2 should be loaded (no plot, just saved text and value information)
    """
     ])

layout_page2 = html.Div([

    ...
    dcc.Textarea(id,...),
    dash_table.DataTable( id=...,... ), # contains values and data which I want to work with/save
    html.Button(id,...children='Submit', ....) # the Submit Button
    ...

])

# index layout
app.layout = url_bar_and_content_div

# complete layout
app.validation_layout = html.Div([
    url_bar_and_content_div,
    layout_page1,
    layout_page2
])

# **Again** , the layout-structure is the **same** as that one in the 3rd code example in https://dash.plotly.com/urls

# callbacks etc.
```

So page 2 consists of a DataTable which mainly consists of text descriptions and values (of many types, str, float, int, NaN etc.). Whenever I click on a line/row on the DataTable, its text gets displayed on the Textarea-field above. And when I click on the "Submit"-button, all the displayed text and values should then be finally "saved" and somehow redirected to page 1 and displayed on the 'data-display'-component (see code again).

My question: How do I do that? How do I program a temporary df which saves text from layout_page2 and displays it on layout_page1?

Here the callback which does the data display on dcc.Textarea when a not-empty DataTable-cell gets clicked:

```py
@app.callback([Output('textarea-p2','value'),  # the Text-block where the text from DataTable gets shown
               Output('datatable-p2','selected_cells'),
               Output('datatable-p2','active_cell')]
              [Input('datatable-p2','active_cell')],
              [State('datatable-p2','data'),
               State('textarea-p2','value')])
def update_data_display(active_cell, data_cells, displayed_text):
    if dash.callback_context.triggered[0]['prop_id'].split('.')[0] == 'datatable-p2':
        ...
        if not pd.isnull(data_cells[row][col]):
            content = text on that 'row' of DataTable + '\n' # work with active_cells and a df = pd.DataFrame(data_cells)
            ...
            displayed_text += content
    return displayed_text, [], None 
#"[], None" so that every time I click on a cell it gets unmarked again, just for clarification
```

What should I change on that callback *update_data_display* for the next step of sending the Text-block-data to 'data-display' on page 1?
And also how should my callback on the "Submit"-button look like then?

Should both of my layout_pagex have a dcc.Store()-component? So how do I proceed with it now?

Comment: I don't know, but, if a plot is a view of data in your app, you need to modify the data in the app, not in the plot.

Comment: I'd also add, you should be able to get to the essence of your problem with a very small and complete code example. I don't mean posting the code you're trying to get working, I mean recreating the simplest example of the problem (synching plots). See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @PeterWood Here, I added some generalized code